# jQuery UI dialog styling and size issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm making a jQuery UI Dialog. It's appearing perfectly fine and my styling works, but the first paragraph element is massive in the dialog.

[image: Screenshot of large paragraph]

The CSS isn't setting anything other than font. If I add `max-height: 1.5em;` then they all pile up on top of each other like below.

[image: Element "stacking"]

I have no clue what is doing this, but my code is below. I have a feeling it is due to the content elsewhere on the page forcing the element to move.

```css
    #cadEditor {
      display: none;
      z-index: 999999 !important;
      background: #222;
    }

    .ui-dialog {
      background: #222;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
      background: #333;
      height: 40px;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: fit-content;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #cadEditor p {
      max-height: 1.5em;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
      display: none;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-button {
      color: #fff;
      background: #222;
      padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
      border: #000000 1px solid;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 1em;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="cadEditor">
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
    <p>Test Dialog</p>
</div>
<script>
    function showCadEditor(button) {
        $('#cadEditor').dialog({
            dialogClass: "cadEditorDialog",
            autoOpen: true,
            title: "Editing Cad " + $(button).attr("forcad"),
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 600,
             buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    }

    showCadEditor();
</script>
```

Comment: When removing the max-height on your Code Snippet example, it looks still fine. Can you verify that and compare to your original code? If yes, and your original has still the issue, might you provide a link to the original?

Comment: Annoyingly I can't provide a link as the site is password protected. The dialog works on its own, but doesn't in the site itself, which is why I think the content is affecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by `position: absolute;` to the dialog content (`#cadEditor`).

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your question to html. Looks good for me.
Can you please explain your question more detail?
May be site's style overwrites the popup's styles.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> <title>Title Goes Here</title> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #cadEditor {
      display: none;
      z-index: 999999 !important;
      background: #222;
    }

    .ui-dialog {
      background: #222;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
      background: #333;
      height: 40px;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: fit-content;
      text-align: center;
    }

    #cadEditor p {
      max-height: 1.5em;
    }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
      display: none;
    }
    
    body{color: white}
</style>
</head>
    <body> <p>This is my web page</p>
    <div id="cadEditor">
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
        <p>Test Dialog</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        function showCadEditor(button) {
            $('#cadEditor').dialog({
                dialogClass: "cadEditorDialog",
                autoOpen: true,
                title: "Editing Cad " + $(button).attr("forcad"),
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 600,
                 buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }

        showCadEditor();
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's something to do with my site's sidebar (navigation menu). My page hides it when the screen is narrower than 700 px and when it gets hidden, the dialog looks fine.

Comment: Nope, it's to do with the bar's size. is there any way to make a div unaffected by everything?